# String.format prints wrong hours

Tags: java, timezone, string.format

I am using String.format to print elapsed time. This is working great for minutes:seconds...

```
long millis = 330000;
String.format("%tMm%tSs", millis, millis);
```

...will print 05m30s.

However, when I try to include hours in my elapsed time, hours is shown as 19! At first I thought it was my locale, but I've tried the following...

```
long millis = 330000;
String.format(Locale.ITALY, "%tHh%tMm%tSs", millis, millis, millis);
```

...and I still get 19h05m30s.

You can even try

```
long millis = 0;
String.format(Locale.ITALY, "%tHh", millis);
```

but you still get 19h.

What's going on?

Comment: What do you mean by "when I try to include hours in my elapsed time"?

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot a formatter in my format string. I've edited the question.

Comment: i am getting `01h05m30s` for the second one

Comment: what timezone are you in?

Comment: https://ideone.com/jFrNly

Comment: I'm in BST and it outputs 1 hour for me, so it looks like it is adjusting to your timezone

Comment: I've changed my system timezone, it looks like that was the issue. I should have tried that first, but I thought the Locale parameter would help. Thanks

Comment: read specification, you need to put date format into args,
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

Comment: @naugler Locale has nothing to do with time zone. Locale is about (1) localization of human language (names of month and day-of-week etc.) and (2) culture-appropriate default formats for building string representations of date-time values (does the date come before or after the month, etc.). Perfectly okay to use a Québec locale (`Locale.CANADA_FRENCH`) with a Turkey time zone, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `long` value is being treated as a `java.util.Date`, not a duration.  That is why the timezone is affecting it.  Your millis value is equivalent to a Date representing 00:05:30 January 1, 1970 **UTC**.

Try making the time relative to midnight in the local timezone:

```
long millis = 330000;

System.out.printf("%THh%<tMm%<tSs%n", millis);

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

cal.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, (int) millis);

System.out.printf("%THh%<tMm%<tSs%n", cal);
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the root issue. I knew that it would treat the value as a date, but I WANTED to represent 00:05:30 January 1, 1970 (the hours, minutes, and seconds are still just elapsed time from 00:00:00 January 1, 1970), however I wasn't aware of the way the timezone would be handled. See my own answer.

Answer (score 1):

## Joda-Time

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library has classes to intelligently handle a span of time, letting you avoid dealing with milliseconds.

## ISO 8601

The [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard defines a format similar to what you are trying to use. The Joda-Time library uses ISO 8601 formats by default for both parsing and generating such strings.

## Don’t Work So Hard

So in other words, you are working too hard. Let Joda-Time 2.7 do the work here.

Better to specify your desired time zone than to rely implicitly on the JVM’s current default time zone (which could change at any moment).

Use [proper time zone names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). Never use the 3 or 4 letter codes which are neither standardized nor unique.

```
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID ( "Europe/Rome" );
```

Fake some data by capturing the current moment, then back off some hours, minutes, and seconds.

```
DateTime now = DateTime.now ( zone );
DateTime then = now.minusHours(19).minusMinutes(5).minusSeconds ( 30 );
```

Represent a span of time in two ways. First, a pair of fixed points on the timeline. Second, a number of months, days, hours, etc.

```
Interval interval = new Interval( then, now );  // String representation defaults to the pair of date-time values displayed in ISO 8601 format.
Period period = interval.toPeriod();  // String representation defaults to ISO 8601 format of PnYnMnDTnHnMnS.
```

Note that the `Period` class’ `toString` method by default generates a string in the ISO 8601 standard format similar to yours, `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS`. The `P` marks the beginning while the `T` separates the date portion from the time-of-day portion.

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "interval: " + interval );
System.out.println ( "period: " + period );
```

When run.

```
interval: 2015-04-18T12:16:55.700+02:00/2015-04-19T07:22:25.700+02:00
period: PT19H5M30S
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [Formatter doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html):

> For long, Long, and Date the time zone used is the default time zone
>   for this instance of the Java virtual machine. The Formatter's locale
>   will supersede the locale of the argument (if any).

I guess the Locale argument is purely for formatting and not time calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this example:

```
int s = 330;
System.out.println(String.format("%d:%02d:%02d", s/3600, (s%3600)/60, (s%60)));
```

I used seconds but that example will also work for miliseconds but You have to add 000 to every digit in example :)

Comment: Not what I asked, but yes I ended up doing something like this to avoid the timezone issues. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Check the [modifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html), for hours it is `tl` not `tHh`.

Comment: H is a valid modifier for hours of a 24 hour clock, and I want to print the letter "h" after the hours

Comment: The same result, but `3h05m30s` instead of `03h05m30s`